# Error when using chrome.notifications.create "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'create' of undefined"

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-app

Hi I get an error when calling chrome.notifications.create from inside a function in the js of a chrome app. Can be used fine from outside a function but when within a function I get the following error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'create' of undefined

Here is the code:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
document.getElementById('submit').addEventListener('click', submit);
});
function submit() {
  var options = {
    type:"basic",
    title:"nameVal",
    message:"msgVal",
    iconUrl:"icon.png",
  };
  //notification options set
  chrome.notifications.create(options,callback);
  //notification set
}
function callback() {
  console.log("Notification succesfull");
  //notification confirmed
}
```

Thanks, I'm a noob when it comes to js and chrome apps so any help is appreciated :)

Answer (score 31, accepted):

There are 2 possible causes.

- You are trying to use this from a [content script](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts). You can't: content scripts are very limited in what Chrome APIs they can call.

  > However, content scripts have some limitations. They cannot:
  >
  > Use chrome.* APIs, with the exception of:
  > `extension` ( `getURL` , `inIncognitoContext` , `lastError` , `onRequest` , `sendRequest` )
  > `i18n`
  > `runtime` ( `connect` , `getManifest` , `getURL` , `id` , `onConnect` , `onMessage` , `sendMessage` )
  > `storage`

  In that case, you need to delegate this call to a background script: [send a message](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging) from the content script, get it in a background script and execute the action.
- You are trying to call it from an extension script, but did not declare the `"notifications"` permission.

  In that case the fix is trivial - just add the permission.

Answer (score 13):

Have you added the chrome notifications permissions to your manifest.json?

adding `permissions: ["notifications",//other permissions here]`

The permissions deals with what is and isnt loaded in your extension, and what you have access too.

Comment: This is better than my answer.

Comment: I already had this in the manifest.json file thanks tho. I'm really confused

Comment: Just looked at documentation, I think your callback function needs to have the notificationID parameter like so `function callback(notificationId) {...}`. If that doesnt work, try removing the callback function reference from the create() function so its just `...create(options);`

Answer (score 0):

I have one case for this undefined question when I use chrome.notifications.

```
var options = {
            type: "basic",
            title: "Extention Title",
            message: 'Extention Message",
            iconUrl: "images/icon_86.png" // My Case:Error in iconUrl
        };
```

But my 'icon_86.png' is not in the images folder.

**Solution: It will be ok when I use my correct iconUrl.**

*('icon_86.png', it is in my project root directory)*